# When does the 2018 Winter Bash end?

Tags: support, winter-bash, winter-bash-2018

On the [blog](https://stackoverflow.blog/2018/12/12/winter-bash-2018-2/) we are told "that on January 2 all hats will be taken back to storage."

Does that mean the Winter Bash includes the second or is the first the last day?

Times help clear up ambiguity: does WB end on Jan 2 0000 UCT or Jan 3 0000 UCT?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [FAQ](https://winterbash2018.stackexchange.com/faq)

> #### What is going on? Why do I see hats?
>
> From December 12th through January 1st, you'll be able to earn hats all over the sites!

That means that Winter Bash 2018 ends on 2019-01-02 00:00 UTC.